# Pandas Dataframe, easier syntax to drop rows by condition on values

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, filtering

Consider a Pandas Dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,2],[1,0],[7,99]],index=[3,4,8], columns = ["R1","R2"])
```

Giving:

```
   R1  R2
3   0   2
4   1   0
8   7  99
```

When I want to remove a row via a condition on a value I either use

```
df = df.drop(df[df["R1"] == 1].index)
```

Or

```
df = df.drop(df.index[np.where(df["R1"] == 1)[0]])
```

Or

```
df = df.drop(df.loc[df['R1'] == 1].index)
```

Both is super cumbersome. Do you know a easier syntax to achieve this?

For example, if there was something like a idrop function, the second option would be more readably:

```
df = df.idrop(np.where(df["R1"] == 1)[0])
```

EDIT:

I had assumed that `df = df[df['R1'] != 1]` is less performant then just dropping a row. (Huge Database...)

Comment: Why do you even need to drop? just select. `df = df.drop(df[df["R1"] == 1].index)` can be `df = df[df['R1'] != 1]`

Comment: It is not the same question. In the oder question it is asked to to access rows based on a condition. I am asking for the easiest syntax to drop rows.

Comment: Is this the same? I had assumed that `df = df[df['R1'] != 1] ` is less performant then just dropping a row. (Huge Database...)

Comment: @jezrael it is not a duplicate

Comment: Why would it be? Something still needs to check if a given row has that value. If anything, getting only the correct rows from the DB to begin with will (should) be the fastest. Check `pd.read_sql`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comparison. It makes sens what you are saying. It anyway must go through the database.  Also does not change if using inplace = True.

Comment: @newandlost - if use db the fastest is filter in database, like DeepSpace pointed. Btw, in pandas should be obviously simple rule - more functions is slowier - `boolena indexing` vs `boolena indexing + drop` here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *boolean indexing* is faster like `drop` and, if need improve performance, use `numexpr`:

[image]

```
import perfplot, numexpr

def bi1(df):
    return df[df['R1'].values != 1]

def bi2(df):
    return df[df['R1'] != 1]

def drop1(df):
    return df.drop(df[df["R1"] == 1].index)

def drop2(df):
    return df.drop(df.index[df["R1"] == 1])

def drop3(df):
    return df.drop(df.loc[df['R1'] == 1].index)

def drop4(df):
    return df.drop(np.where(df["R1"] == 1)[0])


def ne(x):
    x = x['R1'].values
    return x[numexpr.evaluate('(x != 1)')]

def q(x):
    return x.query('R1 != 1')

def ev(x):
    return x[x.eval('R1 != 1')]


def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'R1':np.random.randint(100, size=n)})
    return df
```

---

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[bi1, bi2,drop1,drop2,drop3,drop4,ne,q,ev],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```